# Kibana: Not able to maximize panel permanently

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, dashboard

In Kibana 8.6.2, I would like to maximize a panel permanently.
So, I click on the panel's *"Options" > "Maximize panel"*:

[image]

However, when I load the Kibana dashboard next time, the panel is minimized again.

It does not work either when I switch to edit mode before and click on "Save" afterwards:

[image]